# New Facebook Comments Plugin shows both english and native language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I've implemented the new Facebook Comments Plugin on my website, and I've specified "swedish" as desired language (js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3). But some words in the comment plugin are still in english, such as "add a comment", "x comments", "also post on facebook", "sort by" and "post". And some words are in swedish, which makes the comment section look ugly and unprofessional. Has any one else experienced this? Any solution?

Comment: Pretty sure that’s simply because Facebook has not all of their UI translated into other languages fully yet.

Comment: This is a bug being tracked here: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/827385934013541/

Comment: Thanks. Seems the only thing to do then is wait.